# how to package the file outside src code maven project

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I have file at the pom.xml level and I want to include that in the package while the maven builds. I have tried , maven-compiler-plugin but nothing helped.
Are there any other ways to handle this scenario, Please help!

Directory structure:

```
jenkinsfile
src
pom.xml
file
```

Comment: Look up how to add *resources*  in Maven. The compiler plugin has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to include a filE, you can use include pattern as mentioned here
    https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

Example snippet is below:

```
    <build>
       <resource>
          <directory>src/resources/yaml</directory>
           <includes>
             <include>*.yml</include>
           </includes>
       </resource>
    </build>
```

Comment: This didnt package the yml file outside the scr code. why did we try to reference resource/yaml here? My file isnt available there. Could you please help me understand